# IF statement error with checking column condition

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe below and want to check every number by column with a certain condition.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[10,3,1], [3,7,2], [2,4,4]], columns=list("ABC"))
```

If any one cell in the columns meets the certain condition by column. I will then execute some codes accordingly.

```
if (df['A'] > 8) | (df['B'] > 6) | (df['C'] > 5):
   print(df.loc[: 'A']) #print function here is just an example
```

The error message says:

> alueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

How can I solve my IF statement to execute the Print code?

Comment: `(df['A'] > 8) | (df['B'] > 6) | (df['C'] > 5)` is a series like `[True, True, False]`. So there is not one truthy/falsy value, that is why it is ambiguous. You want True if all of them should be true with `((df['A'] > 8) | (df['B'] > 6) | (df['C'] > 5)).all()` or True is atleast one of them is true like `((df['A'] > 8) | (df['B'] > 6) | (df['C'] > 5)).any()`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I will use .any() to solve my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if any((df['A'] > 8) | (df['B'] > 6) | (df['C'] < 2)):
   print(df.loc[:, 'A']) #print function here is just an example
```

just like your error points, use `any(iterable)` or `(iterable).any()` in your case, to test for multiples of true/false statements

P.S. plus you're missing a comma in the `df.loc[:, 'A']`

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I learn 'any(iterable)' to use for my situation. And thanks to pointing out my error of missing a comma.